# Ngrx selector undefined EntityAdapter

Tags: angular, ngrx

going round in circles on this. Everytime i seem to use the selector it's undefined.  I checked other posts and the code they were missing i already have.  I keep getting undefined when using the selector.  I have ngrx devtools setup as well.  Any help would really be appreciated.

**Component:**

```
import * as fromBusiness from '@app/@store/reducers/index';

    ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.params.id;
    this.business$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromBusiness.getBusinessEntityById(), { id }))
    .pipe(
      map((business: BusinessModel) => {
        return this.business = business;
      }),
    );
    console.log(this.business);
  }
```

**Feature module**

```
StoreModule.forFeature('businesses', fromBusiness.businessFuncReducer),
```

**Reducer:**

```
export interface State extends EntityState<BusinessModel> {}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<BusinessModel> = createEntityAdapter<
  BusinessModel
>( {
  selectId: (business: BusinessModel) => business.id,
});

export const initialState = adapter.getInitialState({});

export const businessReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  //reducer methods here, upsertone, addone etc
);

export function businessFuncReducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
  return businessReducer(state, action);
}

export const businessFeatureSelector = createFeatureSelector<State>(
  'businesses'
);

export const {
  selectIds,
  selectEntities,
  selectAll,
  selectTotal,
} = adapter.getSelectors();


export const getAllBusinesses = createSelector(
  businessFeatureSelector,
  selectAll
);
```

**reducer.index.ts**

```
export interface State {
  business: fromBusiness.State;
}

export const selectBusinessState = createFeatureSelector<fromBusiness.State>(
  'businesses'
);

export const selectBusinessEntities = createSelector(
  selectBusinessState,
  fromBusiness.selectEntities
);

export const getBusinessEntityById = () => {
  return createSelector(
    selectBusinessEntities,
    (entities: Dictionary<BusinessModel>, props: {id: string}) => {
      return entities[props.id];
    },
  );
};
```

Appreciate any help on this. Spent 2 days without a solution.  Attached is a screenshot of the devtools tree.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just double the imports and make sure it's correct. The issue may not be with the selector being used but maybe one of the parent ones?

Comment: I tried the parent levels and I always get undefined, no matter what selector i try.  I'm wondering if the app module is setup correctly.
i have:

StoreModule.forFeature('businesses', businessFuncReducer),

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it wasn't the selectors or the module.  It was just how i was consuming it.  The examples around didn't work for me, so i did it slightly different way.